How to add a trigger to a driver?
I have a bone(Bone A) that is rotating another bone(Bone B) with a driver with a custom expression, and it works.
But I only want Bone B to start rotating after Bone A has rotated on the y axis 45º.
How can I create this trigger?

just add an if expression to your driver? so if you now have something like "ab" then you add "ab if c > pi/4 else 0"

Cool. I know nothing about coding whatsoever, I'm just stringing things together as I find them to get what I want since bone constraints aren't great.

..or a lazy and?  .. rY_a > pi/4 and rY_a or maybe rY_a > pi/4 and rY_a - pi/4 to avoid the jump

Or multiply by a 0/1 variable... However the "start rotating" part suggests to me this is really this problem: animating sine wave expression, which comes from misunderstanding how drivers work: drivers don't define change, they define final state (of a single value). With the right formula they give you an impression of a smooth change, but this impression is broken if you switch between the result of the formula and some other formula or simple value. As suggested by me under the link, you may want to use a simulation zone in geonodes...

Please [Edit] your question to clarify what you want to achieve. Consider creating a simple scene rather than sharing your actual work, which would add friction to our understanding of your problem.
